# How to move OOTB profile properties into custom section

Tags: powershell, user-profile-property, ordering

How to move OOTB user profile properties into custom section? How we can do it using powershell? I need a PowerShell script for doing this in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Command seems to work to change the DisplayOrder, and the new values show up when listed fresh, ***but*** this doesn't seem to result in the property actually showing up in a different order on the edit profile page?

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the properties by executing the following PowerShell commands:

```
$MySite = Get-SPSite "MySiteHostURL"
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $MySite
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$profilemanager.properties | ft name,displayorder
```

Then you can change the order of any property by doing this:

```
$profileManager.Properties.SetDisplayOrderByPropertyName("MyProperty",75)
$profileManager.Properties.CommitDisplayOrder()
```

Play around with the display order a bit and you will be able to move your properties into Custom Section.